# 10-year old Sven Pro 1000 UPS turns off if load is low - batteries are good

Tags: power-supply, power, ups

I have a Sven Pro 1000 UPS which is 10 years old. However, it still works good after replacing its batteries twice. The only problem is that it automatically turns off if the load is very low - for example, if only a home WiFi router is attached. Is there a way to configure this UPS so it will provide backup power even if its load is low?

Comment: Have you tried to find a manual for it, e.g. using https://archive.org/web/? You know "read" the manual :-)

Comment: @Hannu, I did read the manual and did install the UPS software trying to find the setting I need. No luck. Perhaps, there is a low-level setting I could configure through the command line and COM/USB interface - IDK. That's why I asked.

Comment: Well, the problem is then to find out; but it may also be that it is pure electronics - without software accessible settings. In that case it may be a trigger level (e.g. for "no load present, let us shut down") that has "moved" probably due to component age.